# P(X<Y) for bivariate normal X,Y

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

When $X\sim N(\mu_x,\sigma^2_x)$ and $Y\sim N(\mu_y,\sigma^2_y)$ are independent, it is known that $P(X<Y) = \Phi(\frac{\mu_y-\mu_x}{\sqrt{\sigma^2_x+\sigma^2_y}})$. Is there a similar closed form expression for $P(X<Y)$ when $X$ and $Y$ are bivariate normal with nonzero correlation?

Comment: Yes, since $X-Y$ is univariate normal.

Comment: Heres a hint: $X-Y$ can be written as a linear combination of $X$ and $Y$, ie $X-Y = [1, -1]^\intercal [X, Y]$

Comment: perfect thank you

Comment: @sayda If you feel you know the answer, you could write it up & accrue points for it.